# How to find the default css class name of React components?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add style to a ProSidebar. Here is the code snippet:

```
<ProSidebar className="MySidebar">
  <SidebarHeader className="MySidebarHeader">
    ...
  </SidebarHeader>
</ProSidebar>
```

And the css:

```
.MySidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}    
.MySidebarHeader{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

But later I found examples which has the class names like:

```
.pro-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.pro-sidebar-inner {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

These seem to be the default class names for ProSidebar. Where can I find these default names? Do other components have such default css classes? Is there any documentation on that?

Comment: What do you mean "default"? If you look at the component source code markup you'll see what classes are in place initially. What you see in the browser document inspector may be after modification.

Comment: Your question about "other components" is quite broad. Are you asking for documentation on ProSidebar or _all_ React components ever?

Comment: @isherwood By "default" I mean that if I have in css the .pro-sidebar class, I don't have to specify the class name. Such as <ProSidebar /> already uses that class in css. By asking other components I was wondering if there is any standard on this pattern for all the other React libraries, so that when I import a new library, I know where to look for these names.

Comment: Please update your question to make that more clear. Don't tell us down here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding where this information is, there is a partial file in the `scss` folder like [_sidebar.scss](https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar/blob/d0546843da52d3f1aa2b3a616774abadf8ad76fb/src/scss/partials/_sidebar.scss#L30) that is establishing the `.pro-sidebar` width for example. You would need to go to the [variables.scss file](https://github.com/azouaoui-med/react-pro-sidebar/blob/d0546843da52d3f1aa2b3a616774abadf8ad76fb/src/scss/variables.scss) to substitute in your own variables, OR, just remove the style from the partials that you want to have control of all together.

That said, adding the `!important` flag, changing your classnames to the one's ProSidebar is using, or removing the `!default` flag from whatever variables in the `variables.scss` file you don't want to show up might work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the class names in developer console. In developer console -> Elements Tab if you expand elements you can find class names.
Yes other elements can have default class names.
Try adding !important to css styles to overwrite styles for the default class names or new class names.